# Combine convolve filter in matlab

Tags: matlab, convolution

Is there a way to take the low pass and high pass filters in the following code and combine them into a single kernel and apply one conv2() function?

**note**: length(lfilter) = 21, length(hfilter) = 81.

what we are basically doing in the last step is saying to remove the large objects from the image (after already removing the very small objects with a Gaussian blur).

```
properties (Constant)
    minStar = 2; % min star radius
    maxStar = 8; % max star radius
    threshold = 12;
end
```

---

```
    function filter2(this)
        normalize = @(x) x/sum(x);
        lfilter = normalize(exp(-((-ceil(5*this.minStar):ceil(5*this.minStar))/(2*this.minStar)).^2));
        hfilter = normalize(exp(-((-ceil(5*this.maxStar):ceil(5*this.maxStar))/(2*this.maxStar)).^2));
        this.low = conv2(lfilter',lfilter,this.raw,'same');
        this.high = conv2(hfilter',hfilter,this.raw,'same');
        this.filtered = this.low - this.high;
        this.foreground = this.filtered > this.threshold;
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the answer in the matlab forums. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/169713-combine-convolution-filters-bandpass-into-a-single-kernel

The gist is that you have to use padding to fill in both sides of the shorter filter, and then  you can just combine the vectors.

Convolution is a linear operation so yes, you can combine the two filtering operations into one. Just make the filters the same size and add/subtract them. For example:

```
 lfilter = normalize(exp(-((-ceil(5*minStar):ceil(5*minmax))/(2*this.minStar)).^2));
 hfilter = normalize(exp(-((-ceil(5*maxStar):ceil(5*minmax))/(2*this.maxStar)).^2));
 padlength = (length(hfilter) - length(lfilter))/2;
 lfilter = padarray(lfilter, [0 padlength]);
 lhfilter = lfilter - hfilter;
 this.filtered = conv2(lhfilter',lhfilter,this.raw,'same');
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the convolution operator is associative:

```
conv( a, conv(b,c) ) == conv( conv(a,b), c )
```

you should be able to combine the two kernels into one just by convolving them with each other.

In your case something like this should work:

```
new_kernel = conv2(lfilter',lfilter, conv2(hfilter',hfilter), 'same');
```

Convolution is commutative as well so the order in which you perform the convolutions shouldn't matter.

**EDIT**: as I explain in the comment below, the asker's method of performing four 1D convolutions ends up being faster than a single 2D convolution.

Comment: I was looking to combine the filters into one kernel. To reduce the number of convolutions (I need to port this eventually to a GPU)

Comment: I see. Using many 1D filters rather than a large 2D filter seems like a better idea. Assuming all of the 1D filters you have are vectors with `N` components and that the image is `M` by `M` pixels, your original method would require `4*N*M*M` multiplications. Mine would actually require `N*N*M*M` if we assume the new kernel combined is `N` by `N`.

Comment: Yea, I want the kernel seperable, the gpu loves, that. Just posted the answer I got.